# Web don´t load when i use cookie-parser in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cookies

I'm trying to get the value of a cookie with a cookie-parser.
The code is as follows (app.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies);
});
```

The log shows the cookies and their value but the page shows the error **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

If I do not use this, the web loads perfectly.

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Every middleware function must either invoke the next one in the chain to continue request processing, or finish the response by itself (using `res.end()` or `res.send(...)` or similar functions). In your case you're not passing control to next middleware, so response is ending with your function - but you're not properly ending the response either. That's why the error.

If you just want to print cookie value, you can invoke the next middleware in chain by using :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies);
    next(); //--> Added to call next middleware in chain
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this at the bottom?

```
app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: Yes, i have it.